# rails foobar_path(3) returnes strange path: "/foobar.3/" instead of "/foobar/3/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Hi i have this starnge behavoir...

```
<%= link_to image_tag("image.png"), brain_path(1), :method => "put" %>
```

produces:

```
<a href="/brain.1" onclick="var f = document.createElement('form'); f.style.display = 'none'; this.parentNode.appendChild(f); f.met ...[many rails code]... ;return false;"><img alt="Research_4" src="/images/image.png" /></a>
```

**a href="/foobar.1"** this is the strange part :( any ideas whqt is causing this?

rake routes gives the following:

> new_brain GET    /brain/new(.:format)               {:controller=>"brains", :action=>"new"}

```
   edit_brain GET    /brain/edit(.:format)              {:controller=>"brains", :action=>"edit"}
        brain GET    /brain(.:format)                   {:controller=>"brains", :action=>"show"}
              PUT    /brain(.:format)                   {:controller=>"brains", :action=>"update"}
              DELETE /brain(.:format)                   {:controller=>"brains", :action=>"destroy"}
              POST   /brain(.:format)                   {:controller=>"brains", :action=>"create"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How do you route your foobar? (singular or plural? resource or resources?)
2. Are you sure that you're using `foobar_path(1)`, not `foobars_path(1)` (singular form)

in real life `foobars_path(1)` will return **/foobars.1** and `foobar_path(1)` - **/foobar/1**

as I see you have to use `brain_path(1)` not `brain_path(1)`

**UPD**

Change your route.rb

```
map.resources :brain
```

it will be better if you'll rename your controller into pluralize *brains* - it is more conventional when you are using resources

Comment: hi thanks for your reply

in routes.rb i use map.resource :brain

yes i'm sure that i use brain_path(1)

Comment: Change `map.resource :brain` to `map.resources :brain` (note the plural) and then it will work. If you don't want/need the index action you can do `map.resources :brain, :except => [:index]`

Comment: rspeicher is right, you can't use brain/1 (brain_path(1)) because you've got ONLY ONE BRAIN when you route brain as a RESOURCE (singular!). As you can see in rake:routes you haven't got /brain/:id resource. So, you need to change your route.rb to __map.resources :brain__